# Many C++ compile errors in iPhone project

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors

i am working on a `C++` file in `Xcode 4.5` on my `iPhone` application.
for some reason the compiler do not accept `C++` statements, it gaves me many errors.
why does this happen?

[image]

any help would be appreciated!
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CAStreamBasicDescription.h` and `CAXException.h` contain C++ code. They can only be included from C++ or Objective-C++ source files.

The errors indicate that the file that is including those two headers is not being compiled as C++ or Objective-C++. The references to `Class` within the errors suggest that it's being compiled as plain Objective-C instead. Ensure that the file has a `.mm` file extension if you do intend it to be compiled as `Objective-C++`, and check that the `Type` is not set to a non-default value in the `Identity and Type` section of the File inspector.

Comment: i know, the file exists in the project. and even in the compile sources .